# How to separate pm2 out logs by time (daily) or by log size?

Tags: linux, node.js, forever, pm2

I use pm2 in the Node server. I want to save the log, separated by time or by logfile size.

```
$pm2 start test_node.js -o out.log --log-date-format "YYYY HH:MM"
```

I save the logs to do daily reporting.

How can I do it?

Comment: Try using logrotate ?

Comment: I don't want add process...
I want separate logs by only pm2 :(